# AttributeError: module 'jsonpath' has no attribute 'jsonpath' while running a robot File in automation on iOS Mac

Tags: python, ios, macos, robotframework, attributeerror

**Python Function :

```
import json
import jsonpath


def read_locator_from_json(locatorname):
    f = open('/Users/mayankamukhija/CAMobileRegression/club_mobile_ios_regression/JsonFiles/ELE.json')
    response = json.loads(f.read())
    value = jsonpath.jsonpath(response, locatorname)
    return value[0]

keyword in robot Framework :

Read_Element_Locator
    [Arguments]     ${jsonpath}
   ${result}=     read_locator_from_json    ${jsonpath}
    [Return]    ${result}
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code, and it worked in my Windows. Maybe your library is too old?